# The process has no package identity in windows phone C#

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-8

Error:The process has no package identity on the xaml page meanwhile it is running okay on run time
This error occur on usercontrol.

[image]

Comment: Please show your work and exception message as a text.

Comment: ' The process has no package identity. Error trying to open the default application data handle  ' it occur on usercontrol